# Reading file from txt

Tags: c, file

I have a txt file from which I want to read data. The data consists of a project input which has the following properties:

```
numberofProjects
numofActivitiesperProject
numofResources
maxAvailableResources[numofResources]
```

, as well as the duration and resource usage of each activity. For example, if a project has a total number of 30 tasks, we have 30 duration and resource usage of each 30 tasks with a total number of  `numofResources`.

I have successfully read the following from a text file, but could not read other information.

```
numofActivitiesperProject
numofResources
maxAvailableResources[numofResources]
```

To be specific, I could not read data to `activityList [k]->duration` and `activityList [k]->maxResourceUse[j]`.

What could the problem be?

#### Code

```
int numofProjects;
int numofActivitiesperProject;
int numofResources;
int *maxAvailableResources;

typedef struct Activity {
    int id;
    int projectNo;
    int nofPre; //number of predecessors
    int nofSuc;
    int *precedessor; //precedence array
    int *successor; //successor array
    int duration;
    int *maxResourceUse; //resource usage if an activity
} Activity, PActivity;

Activity *activity;
Activity **activityList;

Activity *readFile(char *fileName) {
    int i = 0, j, k;
    int *numOfPres;
    int Total;

    FILE *fd = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open file %s\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fd, "%d%d%d", &numofProjects, &numofActivitiesperProject, &numofResources); 

    maxAvailableResources = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * numofResources);
    for (i = 0; i < numofResources; i++) {
        fscanf(fd, "%d", &maxAvailableResources[i]);
    }


    Total =numofProjects*numofActivitiesperProject;
    activityList = (Activity **) malloc(sizeof(Activity *) * (Total));
    activity=(Activity *) malloc(sizeof(Activity));
    numOfPres = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (Total));
    activity->maxResourceUse = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * numofResources);

    for (k=0;k<Total;k++){
        //activityList [k]->duration = (int) malloc(sizeof(Total));
        activity->id=k+1;
        fscanf(fd, "%d", &(activity->duration));
        for (j = 0; j < numofResources; j++)
            fscanf(fd, "%d", &(activity->maxResourceUse[j]));
        activityList[k]=activity; //THERE IS A PROBLEM HERE...
    }

    }


    fclose(fd);

}   


void main() {
    readFile ("file.txt");
    _getch();
}
```

#### Text file

Txt file from which inputs are read:

```
10                  
10                  
6                       
11  9   7   9   11  20      
20  0   0   0   0   0   5 
goes on like this...
```

Format of input file is as follows:

```
Number of projects
Number of activities per project
Number of resources
R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 ....Rk Total amount of each resource
Duration Activitity-1 of project-1,  Required resources of Activitity-1 of project-1
Duration Activitity-2 of project-1,  Required resources of Activitity-2 of project-1
...
Duration Activitity-n of project-1,   Required resources of Activitity-n of project-1
Duration Activitity-1 of project-2,   Required resources of Activitity-1 of project-2
...

...
Duration Activitity-1 of project-m,   Required resources of Activitity-1 of project-m
Duration Activitity-2 of project-m ,  Required resources of Activitity-n of project-m
```

Comment: Please, format your question properly, and try to come up with a minimal example of your input (just enough to reproduce theproblem you are having). Also, you just have to post the part of the code that stands for your question -- include's and print's rarely count as so.

Comment: i tried to simplfy it.

Comment: ok. I have edited the way you defined. Now ıt comes up with an exception. "Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcde5." do I have a problem with activitylist memory allocation?

Comment: Memory allocations are added. Now I have a new problem. activityList[k]->duration and other activityList[k]->maxResourceUse points same value. Most probabaly due to activityList[k]=activity; assignment. But since activityList is a double pointer ı should use another pointer to point it (activity). How can i solve the problem.